# Shading artifacts on the render

Tags: rendering, mesh, shadows, artifacts

I am trying to model Cap's Shield but when I render it, there are some artifacts near the star. Can anyone tell me what's the issue here?
[image: Render]
[image: Edit Mode]

[Blend File](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51719)
(Please your own hdri since the file would be too long)

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: I've added it now.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Creases, it's not always a good solution (compared to a good topology with bevels etc...), but it looks like if you choose a Subdivision of 2 in the Subsurf modifier it fixes the problem, actually most of the time you don't need more than 2

Comment: Actually I'm using solidify and subsurf modifiers currently but still there are artifiacts as seen in the image.

Comment: yes but as I said, if you decrease your Subsurf subdivisions (View and Render) to 2 this will fix the problem, I guess a high subdivision creates additional faces that try to smooth but actually mess with the topology

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decrease your *Subsurf* subdivisions (*View* and *Render*) down to a value of 2 this will fix the problem, I guess a high subdivision creates additional faces that try to smooth but actually mess with the topology.

[image]